# How to get OSRAM Lightity ClientID and secret?

Tags: smart-home, lighting, smart-lights

I have an OSRAM Lightify light and a bridge. I am able to operate the light operations using the OSRAM Lightify mobile application. OSRAM provides API support for controlling the light operations. I need to get the authorization code for using the below curl command.

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://na.lightify-api.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=cb515518-1b27- 
45da-9821-b86b1c4264b&state= 
{{state}}&redirect_uri=http://your.server.com/&response_type=code'
```

I am stuck with the *client_id*. How can I get the *client_id* and *secret*? The Lightify documentation is available at [Osram Lightify API doc](https://docs.lightify-api.com)

Answer (score 5):

As per [OSRAM Lightify Public API](https://docs.lightify-api.com)

> In order to call the API endpoints you will need a set of valid
> client_id and secret_id.
>
> North America (NA) developers go to https://na-developers.lightify-api.com
>
> Europe, Middle East and Africa (EMEA) developers go to https://emea-developers.lightify-api.com
>
> You will need a Lightify account in the region (NA or EMEA) to register as
> a developer.

Answer (score 3):

Your Lightify account username and password should be sufficient to get you into the developers API area.

There you can create a new client which will generate your client ID and password.

The new process (since 4/1/2018) is oAuth2, so you'll need to set up a receiving page on a server to get the access code from the login process, then use that to get the token you'll need for command requests.